# Array value in range of a specific integer

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I check if elements in an array are between a specific range? Example: `myarray[1]` = `200`, `myarray[13]` = `220`. How do I check if any element in `myarray` is greater than or less than 30 of any other element?

My code so far, ignore the rest, just see the `if` statement:

```
int cnt = 0;
int flg = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myarray.size(); i++){
    if(CHECK IF IN RANGE HERE, HOW?){
        cnt++;
    } else if(myarray[i] < 0){
        flg = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hints: What does `myarray[i]` do? What does `i + 1` do? How can you combine them? And what does `abs(a - b)` do for two integers `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I check if elements in an array are between a specific range?

#### Option 1

1. Sort the array.
2. Find the different between the first element and the last element of the sorted array.
3. Check whether that difference is within the range you expect to see.

#### Option 2

1. Walk through the elements of the array and gather the smallest value and largest value in the array.
2. Find the difference between the smallest element and the largest element.
3. Check whether that difference is within the range you expect to see.

#### Option 3

1. Use `std::min_element()` and `std::max_element()` to get smallest value and largest value in the array.
2. Find the difference between the smallest element and the largest element.
3. Check whether that difference is within the range you expect to see.

Comment: I want to check each element, not only the largest and the smallest.

Comment: @If the difference between the largest and the smallest is smaller than a given range, then difference between any other elements will be smaller than that range too. Isn't that what you were trying to do?

Comment: @Eri. are you interested only in finding out the difference between the `n`-th and the `n+1`-th element for the valid range of `n` in your array?

Comment: I want to check each element each if they differ more than 50 to the rest of the elements.

Comment: @Eri., in that case, my suggestions are what you need. They capture the worst case scenario.

Comment: @R sahu would you mind to show me how this can be done codewise?

Comment: @Eri - try translating the description of Option 2 into code.   It is only a few lines and translating that into code will be a useful learning exercise for you (versus someone providing code will give you an excuse to learn exactly nothing in doing your homework).

Comment: @R Sahu - you might also want to provide an option 3 that uses standard algorithms `min_element()` and `max_element()`.